# How can I relate or combine these two sentences?

Tags: sentence-construction, adverbs, commas, alternatives, sentence-combination

I have the following sentences.

> As it was already discussed, we avoid using absolute paths to locate an anchor node.
>
> We rely on stable attributes such as the content, id, class, etc.

How can I relate or combine them? I thought to say:

> As it was already discussed, we avoid using absolute paths to locate an anchor node. We, **instead**, rely on stable attributes such as the content, id, class, etc.

My questions:

- Is it "instead" a proper or common word for such relation? Do you know other alternative words?
- Can it be in the beginning of the sentence? for example "Instead, we rely on ..."
- Is my usage of comma before and after of the adverb "instead" correct? When it is used?

Answer (score 1):

Because your question was how to combine the two sentences, you'd want to combine them this way:

As already discussed, we avoid using absolute paths to locate an anchor node, instead relying on stable attributes such as the content, id, class, etc.

Your proposed example of two sentences is correct, and reads much more smoothly. Use that example.